Display Issues with Hexo Blog on GitHub: Missing Images and Unclickable Links, What Should I Do?
I've encountered some issues when setting up a personal blog with Hexo and deploying it to GitHub. Here are the problems I've encountered and some details of my operations:
After the initial deployment, the blog page on GitHub lacks image display, which is different from the local preview.
I changed the theme and updated the content and links, but after the update, I found that the blog page still lacks image display, and the links cannot be opened.
I suspect the problem may lie in the process of compiling Hexo into HTML, as the same issue exists when opening the compiled HTML file locally.
I hope someone can help me take a look.
I hope someone can help me take a look. Here is some information that might be needed:
1、GitHub repository URL : text
2、Theme name : micalltheme
3、_config.yml :
# Hexo Configuration
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/configuration.html
## Source: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/

# Site
title: Hexo
subtitle: ''
description: ''
keywords:
author: John Doe
language: en
timezone: ''

# URL
## Set your site url here. For example, if you use GitHub Page, set url as 'https://username.github.io/project'
url: https://github.com/YiLu09/huantian_blog-24-7
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title/
permalink_defaults:
pretty_urls:
  trailing_index: true # Set to false to remove trailing 'index.html' from permalinks
  trailing_html: true # Set to false to remove trailing '.html' from permalinks

# Directory
source_dir: source
public_dir: public
tag_dir: tags
archive_dir: archives
category_dir: categories
code_dir: downloads/code
i18n_dir: :lang
skip_render:

# Writing
new_post_name: :title.md # File name of new posts
default_layout: post
titlecase: false # Transform title into titlecase
external_link:
  enable: true # Open external links in new tab
  field: site # Apply to the whole site
  exclude: ''
filename_case: 0
render_drafts: false
post_asset_folder: true
marked: 
  prependRoot: true
  postAsset: true
relative_link: false
future: true
syntax_highlighter: highlight.js
highlight:
  line_number: true
  auto_detect: false
  tab_replace: ''
  wrap: true
  hljs: false
prismjs:
  preprocess: true
  line_number: true
  tab_replace: ''

# Home page setting
# path: Root path for your blogs index page. (default = '')
# per_page: Posts displayed per page. (0 = disable pagination)
# order_by: Posts order. (Order by date descending by default)
index_generator:
  path: ''
  per_page: 10
  order_by: -date

# Category & Tag
default_category: uncategorized
category_map:
tag_map:

# Metadata elements
## https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta
meta_generator: true

# Date / Time format
## Hexo uses Moment.js to parse and display date
## You can customize the date format as defined in
## http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
date_format: YYYY-MM-DD
time_format: HH:mm:ss
## updated_option supports 'mtime', 'date', 'empty'
updated_option: 'mtime'

# Pagination
## Set per_page to 0 to disable pagination
per_page: 10
pagination_dir: page

# Include / Exclude file(s)
## include:/exclude: options only apply to the 'source/' folder
include:
exclude:
ignore:

# Extensions
## Plugins: https://hexo.io/plugins/
## Themes: https://hexo.io/themes/
theme: micalltheme

# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/one-command-deployment
deploy:
  type: 'git'
  repo: https://github.com/YiLu09/huantian_blog-24-7.git
  branch: main

4、Localhost screenshot :
enter image description here
5、GitHub website screenshot:
enter image description here
I want the pages displayed on GitHub to be exactly the same as those displayed on localhost. If you have any suggestions or need more information, please let me know at any time. Thank you very much for your help!
